# Infinispan Junit 5: CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000501: Cannot persist cache configuration as global state is disabled

Tags: java, infinispan

Using below code block I am able to create a infinispan test factory using Junit5 fraemwork.

```
{

     TestResourceTracker.setThreadTestName("InfinispanServer");
     ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
     EmbeddedCacheManager ecm = TestCacheManagerFactory.createCacheManager(
           new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().nonClusteredDefault().defaultCacheName("default"),
           configurationBuilder);

     HotRodServerConfigurationBuilder serverBuilder = new HotRodServerConfigurationBuilder();
     serverBuilder.adminOperationsHandler(new EmbeddedServerAdminOperationHandler());
     hotRodServer = HotRodTestingUtil.startHotRodServer(ecm, host, port, serverBuilder);
}
```

When I access infinispan using the host and port for unit testing getting below exception, what could be the problem:

> Caused by:
> org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:
> org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000501: Cannot
> persist cache configuration as global state is disabled

-- This piece of code works well with Infinispan 9.4.15 version. Getting exception in Infinispan 11.0.4 version.

Comment: how are you creating your caches?

Comment: Creating caches using RemoteCacheManager.administration().getOrCreateCache()
"default" template used while calling getOrCreateCache()

Answer (score 1):

By default, caches created via Hot Rod client are persisted.

To disable this behaviour use `remoteCacheManager.administration().withFlags(CacheContainerAdmin.AdminFlag.VOLATILE).getOrCreateCache(...);`

For testing, the above should be enough. But, if you need, you can enable the global state by adding `globalState().enable()` to `GlobalConfigurationBuilder`:

```
new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().nonClusteredDefault().defaultCacheName("default").globalState().enable()
```

Comment: Was the `nonClusteredDefault` method removed recently? Can't find it with latest version.

Comment: It is available in ISPN 13 and ISPN 14-dev: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/13.0.x/core/src/main/java/org/infinispan/configuration/global/GlobalConfigurationBuilder.java#L56